# how to run examples of a rust project

Tags: rust, rust-cargo

1/ It happened to me run examples in this repo https://github.com/0xProject/OpenZKP

One of way to an example is

```
cargo run --release --example small_fib
```

I'm just curious why we can run the example `small_fib` at the root directory even the example small_fib is located in a subdir project as this repo consists of multiple projects.

2/ Another question is that the `small_fib` example was not specified in example section of the Cargo.toml but we can execute it with

```
cargo run --release --example small_fib
```

Comment: I'd argue this question is not a duplicate of the other one. The title of the question is confusing but the OP is not asking how he can run an example but why it works in his case.

Answer (score 11):

To answer your first question, the `crypto/stark` folder is added to the `workspace` section of the root's `Cargo.toml`. See [the Cargo book](https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/manifest.html#the-workspace-section) about how this section works:

> Whenever any crate in the workspace is compiled, output is placed in the workspace root (i.e., next to the root crate's Cargo.toml).

For your second question, the `small_fib.rs` file is placed in the `examples` folder of `crypto/stark`. It can be run directly as an example. I found [this article](http://xion.io/post/code/rust-examples.html) to be very informative about Rust examples.

> The important thing is that you don’t have to worry what to do with your example code anymore. All you need to do is drop it in the examples/ directory, and let Cargo do the rest.